# cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I have a custom class named `Choice` which has 2 properties: a `string Description;` and `Action A;`

In the main program I define an instance `Choice c = new Choice("Desc", foo);`

Below I define a method `public void foo(AnotherClass AC);`

Now I want to execute the method `foo()` I gotta call either `c.A();` or `c.A.Invoke();` but after compiling both gave me the error `Arugument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'` at the instancing line: `Choice c = new Choice("Desc", foo);`

If I defined `foo` without any arguments such as `public void foo();` it would not give me the problem

How can I fix this ?

EDIT: Here is the minimal code:

```
class Choice
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Action A { get; set; }
    public Choice()
    {
        Description = "";
        A = delegate { };
    }
    public Choice(string Description, Action A) : this()
    {
        this.Description = Description;
        this.A = A;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    // Details of AnotherClass...
}

public void foo(AnotherClass AC)
{
    // do something with AC...
}

static void Main()
{
        AnotherClass Bar; // I want this as an argument into foo()
        Choice c = new Choice("Desc", foo); // I'm stuck here, how do I call foo() with Bar as an argument without changing A's type ?            
        c.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's much easier if you could *show* your code instead of *describing* your code.

Comment: I have updated code

Comment: If the code you've provided *did* compile, what would you expect the value of the `AC` parameter in the `foo` method to be? (As a side-note, I'd strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions even in sample code, just to avoid the unconventional names being distracting.)

Comment: `AC` value is something unrelated to this problem since I want a way to call `foo()` with `AnotherClass` parameter. Defining `foo()` without parameter worked for me as I stated

Comment: I don't see how it's unrelated to the problem: you'd specified a method with a parameter. You're trying to invoke that method. That parameter *will have a value* - so what value do you want it to have? To put it another way: you're effectively trying to call `c.Foo()` - which clearly wouldn't work because you're not providing an argument for the `AC` parameter. If it wouldn't work when calling it directly, how would you expect it to work when doing it indirectly?

Comment: I now understand your question. I have updated the code

Comment: Okay, so how would you expect the second and third lines of `Main` to use `Bar` when they don't mention it anywhere? You could use `Choice c = new Choice("Desc", () => foo(Bar));` (after initializing `Bar` of course)... as Gabriel suggested.

Comment: (And again, I'd strongly recommend using conventional names in your samples.)

Comment: Ok I got the solution thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is an `Action`, which means it's a delegate to a function without any arguments. `foo` does not match that, since it takes an `AnotherClass` argument.

You can:

- change `A`'s type to `Action<AnotherClass>`
- initialize `c` with a parameterless lambda: `Choice c = new Choice("Desc", () => foo(someAnotherClass))`

Comment: Changing A's type is something I cannot do. I tried the second suggestion but it gave me `'AnotherClass' is a type, which is not valid in the given context` error instead

Comment: I fixed the problem by doing the second suggestion by passing the actual argument `Bar` instead of Class type `AnotherClass`: `Choice c = new Choice("Desc", () => foo(Bar))`

Comment: @samyung_c: Gabriel never suggested passing the type itself... `() => foo(someAnotherClass)` seems pretty clear to me...